# entry.Properties[propName].ToString() == "mobile" isn't evaluating as true

Tags: c#, system

```
namespace SignatureCreator
{
    class Program

    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string delimiter = ",";

            // set up domain context
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);


            // find currently logged in user
            UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.Current;
            string displayName = up.DisplayName;
            string title = up.Description;
            string phoneNumber = up.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
            string[] userName = displayName.Split(new string[] { delimiter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string firstName = userName[1];
            string lastName = userName[0];
            firstName = firstName.Substring(1);
            firstName = firstName.ToUpper();
            lastName = lastName.ToUpper();
            Console.WriteLine(firstName +" "+ lastName);
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber);

            DirectoryEntry entry = up.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
            System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection props = entry.Properties;

            /*
             * 
             */

            foreach (string propName in props.PropertyNames)
            {
                if (entry.Properties[propName].ToString() == "mobile")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(propName + " = " + entry.Properties[propName].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(propName + " = NULL");
                }
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to loop through the active directory info to find the user's mobile number. But I can't figure out how to loop through this and return it. Even when I just evaluate the propname == mobile it doesn't return true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output? If "mobile" is in your property list, you should see "mobile = ..." in the output. If it is, common errors are whitespace before or after the string you're looking at, or case disagreement (call ".ToLower()" before comparing).

Comment: some times this problem comes because of an extra space, so for that try to use `Trim()` like `if (entry.Properties[propName].ToString().Trim() == "mobile")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with [**`DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/913td91k.aspx) and it will Loads the values of the specified properties into the property cache.

And also you can check whether given property contains in `DirectoryEntry` by using `DirectoryEntry.Properties.Contains` method . if property exist, you can get value of it without looping all the properties.

```
entry.RefreshCache(new string[]{"mobile"});
if(entry.Properties.Contains("mobile"))
    Console.WriteLine("mobile= " + entry.Properties["mobile"].Value);
else
    Console.WriteLine("mobile  = NULL");
```